# why for loop make crash in browser when put condition in it?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

here is the loop , i want it to run on the given limit provided to it if not limit provided then default run 20 times. but i minimize the one line code by put condition in the loop is that wrong way ? or did i make any syntax error ? or this code is logically wrong ? on internet it when i search it says you can put condition in for loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.limit?this.limit:15; i++) {
  this.files.push(files.item(i));
}
```

here is my for loop code its checking the limit.

Comment: You need parenthesis `i < (this.limit ? this.limit : 15)` or else it will behave like `(i < this.limit) ? this.limit : 15` and will loop infinitely

Answer (score 2):

Due to operator precedence, your expression

```
i < this.limit?this.limit:15
```

is equivalent to

```
(i < this.limit) ? this.limit : 15
```

`<` has precedence 13; the conditional operator has precedence 4. The `<` occurs before the `? :`.

Override it by grouping with `()`s:

```
i < (this.limit ? this.limit : 15)
```

More readably, set the limit *outside* the loop, and use `||` instead of the conditional operator:

```
const limit = this.limit || 15;
for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
```

In case your `this.limit` can be 0, and you'd want to prevent any iterations, since 0 is falsey, the alternate of 15 will occur instead. If that's a possibility, check if the value is 0:

```
const limit = (!this.limit && this.limit !== 0) ? this.limit : 15;
```

or, if you're transpiling, and the limit will be `null` or `undefined`:

```
const limit = this.limit ?? 15;
```